# Faster way to get frame index from a given unsorted vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, optimization, c++98

I'm looking for a way to make this function faster. I did this for my own, so thought could be a better solution. I'm using c++98...

Basically it returns an index of the given currentFrame from given vector of frames with some exceptions.

**The point is, the vector is unsorted and if the currentFrame doesn't exist in the vector, then it should give the nearest frame's index from the left(MIN). If the left one is missing as well, then the right(MAX) one.**

```
int getFrameIndex(double currentFrame, std::vector<double> frames)
{
    int f_index = 0;
    if (frames.size() > 1)
    {   
        int nearFIndex = INT_MIN;
        int minFIndex = INT_MAX;
        std::vector<double>::iterator it;
        for(it = frames.begin(); it != frames.end(); ++it)
        {
            if (currentFrame == *it)
            {
                f_index = static_cast<int>(it - frames.begin());
                break;
            }
            else if (currentFrame > *it && nearFIndex < *it)
            {
                nearFIndex = static_cast<int>(*it);
                f_index = static_cast<int>(it - frames.begin());
                continue;
            }
            else if (*it < minFIndex && nearFIndex == INT_MIN)
            {
                minFIndex = static_cast<int>(*it);
                f_index = static_cast<int>(it - frames.begin());
            }
        }
    }
    return f_index;
}
```

Comment: There is probably not much you can do. Parallelization comes to mind. You might have better luck at [codereview.se].

Comment: If the currentFrame is usually in frames, then the two-pass approach of first finding the frame (ca be done with `std::find()`) and then finding the approximation will be faster, because the first if in the loop will almost always fail.  However it will be slower when the currentFrame is not present.

Comment: maybe pass the vector as a const ref? also take a look at compiler explorer https://godbolt.org it shows you the disassembly realtime